# Adjust terminal size using a system call from within Vim

Tags: vimrc, neovim, external-command, vim-windows, functions

All,

I have a little function I'm trying to fix. I'd like to change my terminal Vim window size using the ASCII escape sequence `\e[8;40;130t` so that my writing window size stays the same when I use a plugin like Tagbar.

The command `printf '\e[8;40;130t'` works within the terminal (iTerm2 with *Disable session-initiated window resizing* unchecked in the profile preference). But the same command, issued through Vim using `exec system("printf '\e[8;40;130t'")` doesn't work.

Here's the full function:

```
" 'F8' toggle Tagbar side-window tag browser
let g:is_tagbar=0
function AdjustWindowWidth()

    exec 'TagbarToggle'

    if (g:is_tagbar==0)
      let g:is_tagbar=1
      call system("printf '\e[8;40;130t'")
    else
      let g:is_tagbar=0
      call system("printf '\e[8;40;100t'")
    endif
endfunction

noremap <F8> :exec AdjustWindowWidth()<CR>
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix the issue?

Sean